# Making a histogram with a log scale

Tags: plotting, histograms, logarithmic-scale

Sorry for my poor english. I am really new in Mathematica. I have a data set and plot it in histogram, The whole script is following:[image: test.jpg]

```
img = ImageResize[Import["test.JPG"], 1000];
img = ImageTrim[img, {{.02, .02}, {.98, .98}}, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
img1 = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img, 0.3], smallSize];
img1 = DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate[img1], smallSize];
img1 = ColorNegate[Binarize[img1]];
img2 = MorphologicalComponents[img1] // Colorize;
img3 = WatershedComponents[img1, Method -> {"MinimumSaliency", 2.0}] //Colorize;
Show[GraphicsGrid[{{img2, img3}}, ImageSize -> 1000, Spacings -> {0, 0}]]

img4 = ColorNegate[img1];
img5 = MorphologicalComponents[img4] // Colorize;
img6 = WatershedComponents[img4, Method -> {"MinimumSaliency", 1.0}] //Colorize;
Show[GraphicsGrid[{{img5, img6}}, ImageSize -> 1000, Spacings -> {0, 0}]]
```

Now I prefer to plot it in log scale so it would be shown as a line with a specific slope. In other words, I want to find the X and y coordinates of the red circles shown in the picture. (The red circles are located as the median of each bin.) And then plot these red points in semi-log scale.
[image]

My code as related to my request.

```
window[list_, {xmin_, xmax_}] := Pick[list, Boole[xmin <= # <= xmax] & /@ list, 1]
data = Tally[Flatten[MorphologicalComponents[img5,CornerNeighbors -> False]]]; 
window[data[[All, 2]], {10, 2000}];
GraphicsGrid[{{img, img5, Histogram[Sqrt[%]]}},
  ImageSize -> 1000, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means for a histogram (log scale or otherwise) to be shown as a line with a specific slope?  I am totally unfamiliar with that concept.

Comment: Sorry so the data is like: Sort[data, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]   {{1, 409318}, {0, 174697}, {189, 1443}, {286, 1056}, {289, 964}, {361,
   903}, {259, 685}.......  The first coordinate is the label of each area and the second is the area of this region. It just label each one based on the region's position in an image. For the semi-log plot, I want the x axis is the  number of the area and y axis is the area. For example: point (9,60) in the semi-log plot means that there are 9 regions with area 60.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is not at all clear what you are asking. We don't have the context you have, so we don't know what `data` is, what your code is supposed to do, what "areas" and "regions" are, etc. Try to explain it in a clear and concise way, so that someone who *has absolutely no idea what you are doing* (we don't) will understand it.

Comment: Do check the second and third options of `Histogram` in the documentation, which show how to do a logarithmic binning or how to make the vertical axis logarithmic.  Search for "log" on the documentation page for several such examples.

Comment: @Jim She probably expect either an exponential distribution or a power-law distribution, which would look "straight" on a linear-log or log-log plot.  But it is not clear.

Comment: Where are `img` and `img5`?

Comment: @Szabolcs I see that the second argument allows the transformation of the raw data and bin widths.  That's good. The third argument with `{"Log",hspec}` can apply a log transform to the frequency/count/density axis.  I can only assume that someone was off their meds when that option was added.  In my original comment I should have said that I am unaware of any defensible argument for having a log scale for the frequency/count axis.  Doing such a transformation completely wipes out the meaning of what a histogram is.  This is not a regression situation where a log scale can make perfect sense.

Comment: Maybe what you mean by potentially obtaining a line is to perform a `QuantilePlot` ?  (i.e., a qq plot).  This compares your data against the expected quantiles from a known distribution.  (Note:  this kind of display has nothing to do with regression or least squares.)

Comment: @JimBaldwin Doing such transformations is in fact quite common.  Also, the `Histogram` function does much more than histograms, so it's not really a concern that the result is not technically that.  Here's an example:  `data = RandomVariate[ParetoDistribution[1, 4], 50000];`.  Now `Histogram[data, PlotRange -> All]` is not particularly informative, while `Histogram[data, "Log", {"Log", "Count"}]` is very much so.  We can also do `Histogram[data, "Log", {"Log", "SurvivalCount"}]`.  There's the revealing straight line, summoned up with a single simple command.

Comment: @Jim Also note that with the vertical axis transformation the ticks are transformed too.  So it is still a proper histogram, just *displayed* in a different way.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think we'll agree to disagree.  The area under the "curve" will not appear constant for comparisons to other histograms and the base line is completely arbitrary.  Yes, many folks do a lot of this but that doesn't make it meaningful.